# Using an if statement to declare the value of a const

Tags: javascript, constants

I have a `const` `numberOfComments` that is the size of an array, i want to have another `const` `riskByComments` that has the value of 5 if `numberOfComments` is higher than 2, otherwise it should be 0.

I know i can do that easily with a `let`, but i know it's better practice to only use `const`

```
    export const calculateRisk = (ticket) => dispatch => {
      const numberOfComments = ticket.comments.length
      let riskByComments//if i use const i need to declare its value
         //right away, i cannot use an if statement to do it later
      if(ticket.comments.length>2){
        riskByComments=5//if i use const inside the if statement
      }else{
         riskByComments=0//i cannot use it in the rest of my function
       }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the conditional operator:

```
const riskByComments = numberOfComments >2 ? 5 : 0;
```